# Property 'position' not found on type java.lang.String

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, el

I am trying to output a primefaces datatable.

```
    <p:dataTable var="bi" value="#{ bowlingInfo.hallMastaren} ">
        <p:column headerText="Position">
            <h:outputText value="#{bi.position }" /> 
        </p:column>
    </p:dataTable>
```

But it won't recognize the data it seems, and throws the below exception.

> javax.servlet.ServletException: /test.xhtml @13,47 value="#{bi.position }": Property 'position' not found on type java.lang.String

I am using primefaces 5.1.

Removing the `<h:outputText value="#{bi.position }" />` will render the page. But it will only render the row once. It was expecting it to render two rows since I add two records.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

With the code provided, this shouldn't happen. However, check that you don't assign a value to `bi` somewhere else on the page, by using `<c:set>` or in some other way. If you do, just rename one of the two `bi` variables.

Comment: Nothing of that sort on the page. You have the complete code.

Comment: Can you put `<h:outputText value="#{bi}" />` on the page, one inside data table and one outside, and see if it prints anything.

Comment: [com.sg.bowlingInfo.Hallmastaren@963294b, com.sg.bowlingInfo.Hallmastaren@47e2df0e] So indeed two objects.

Comment: Was that inside or outside of data table?

Comment: Same, Added a dataList and all of a sudden it started working. No change to the code that I can see. But I created a backingBean to hold the list don't know if that did anything.

Comment: If it printed out that outside of data table, that means that somehow `#{bi}` has a value outside of data table context. Maybe it has something to do with the fact that you are returning a list of the same class which is a managed bean, which isn't a good idea. Maybe it has nothing to do with this issue (I still think it does), but you should separate the managed bean and the class you use as DTO for displaying on the page.

Answer (score 6):

Whitespace is significant in value expressions. Look closer at `value` attributes:

```
<p:dataTable var="bi" value="#{ bowlingInfo.hallMastaren} ">
    <p:column headerText="Position">
        <h:outputText value="#{bi.position }" /> 
    </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

This absolutely isn't right. The trailing space after `}` is causing this all because it ultimately get coerced as a `String`. It's like as if you're doing below in plain Java:

```
Object dataTableValue = bowlingInfo.getHallMastaren() + " ";
```

Get rid of the whitespace in value expressions.

```
<p:dataTable var="bi" value="#{bowlingInfo.hallMastaren}">
    <p:column headerText="Position">
        <h:outputText value="#{bi.position}" /> 
    </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```